# how to see order rank of a correlation matrix using corrgram

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I wanted to generate correlation matrices which are made of correlation of row couples. I used the corrgram function to generate them. In my first attempt, the function generated correlation matrix of which diagonals filled with ranks.

```
corrgram(t(datasetA),order="GW")
```

[image]

a sample of the output

However when I use it for my second dataset, somehow the diagonal of correlation matrix is filled with varxxx strings instead of rank of correlation.

```
corrgram(t(datasetB),order="GW")
```

The datasets contain nearly the same type of values (ints) and they are both dataframe. How can I solve this ?

[image]

Edit:
Here is the list of commands from which generates the correlation matrix contains varxxx's in diagonal

```
erase <- matrix(c(1,5,2,6,8,4,1,5,6),nrow=3)
corrgram(t(erase),order="HC")
```

output:
[image]

Because it is a huge dataset and contains sensitive data, I cannot share the dataset and show the series of operations by which I ended up with the first output above.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] and then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming column names with numbers fixed the issue

```
names(dataSetB)<-c(1:totalNumberOfColumn)
```